# Comparing two array list for specific alphabets of string in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want to compare two strings from array lists.i.e "M1_1" of first list is compare with "M1_3" of other array list. i want only to compare it before "_".
if the alphanumeric before "_" are same i.e "M1" and "M1" are same then display it. i have tried some code but i think it compare the whole string. 
i search the problem but i didn't found it. sorry if it appears in duplicates.
thanks

```
ArrayList<String> str1=new ArrayList<String>();
str1.add("M1_1");  
str1.add("M1_2");  
str1.add("M2_1");
ArrayList<String> str2=new ArrayList<String>();  
 str2.add("M1_3");  
 str2.add("M1_4");  
 str2.add("M2_2");
        for ( String s : Str) {
            for (String s2 : St2) {
                if (Str.equals("string2")) {
                    //do something
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: what do you expect this to do? if (Str.equals("string2")) {  ?? 
really, how about at least posting something that compiles first.

Comment: no Str or St2 is defined in this code. And you have defined both of your ArrayLists as str

Comment: sorry for the typing. yeah i should have been compiled it first.
typing error.
ArrayList<String> str1=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> str2=new ArrayList<String>();

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use substring function to compare a part of two strings

```
ArrayList<String> str=new ArrayList<String>();
    str.add("M1_1");  
    str.add("M1_2");  
    str.add("M2_1");
    ArrayList<String> str2=new ArrayList<String>();  
     str2.add("M1_3");  
     str2.add("M1_4");  
     str2.add("M2_2");
            for ( String s : Str) {
                for (String s2 : St2) {
                    if (s.substring(0,lengthofyoursubstring).equals(s2.substring(0,lengthofyoursubstring))) {
                        //do something
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

inside for loop you can do something like this

```
String s1 = "M1_h";
String s2 = "M2_s";

if(s1.split("_")[0].equalsIgnoreCase(s2.split("_")[0])){
    System.out.println("true");
}else{
System.out.println("false");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Works perfectly. Tested it myself.

```
 ArrayList<String> str1=new ArrayList<String>();
str1.add("M1_1");  
str1.add("M1_2");  
str1.add("M2_1");
ArrayList<String> str2=new ArrayList<String>();  
 str2.add("M1_3");  
 str2.add("M1_4");  
 str2.add("M2_2");
        for ( String s : str1) {
            for (String s2 : str2) {
              if (s.split("_")[0].equals(s2.split("_")[0])) {
                System.out.println(s + " equals " + s2);
                }  
            }
        }
```